# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:1.480

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, jenkins

I am new to CI and Jenkins.
I am importing git project (https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin) into my eclipse but i am getting an error as :

```
"Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer 
org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:1.480 from http//download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven 
was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jgit-repository 
has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:1.480 from/to jgit-repository 
(http//download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven): null to 
http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/plugin/1.480/plugin-
1.480.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM"
```